# Transforming Microsoft Graph ListItem Output to a corresponding C# type

Tags: c#, json, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

The work of transforming JSON data into a typed data model through seems to be made much more complex by the "help" the combination of SharePoint and MS Graph offer. :-)

I have a SharePoint List in Microsoft 365 that I'm accessing through the Graph API in C#, where the query destination is a typed class with properties identical to the SharePoint List Column Properties.

The `ListItem` class Graph API returns the results in the a `Fields.AdditionalData` of type `Dictionary<string,object{System.Text.Json.JsonElement}>` It needs to become an `IEnumerable<DataItem>`, which I can do by taking the List from the query result through a Serialize/Deserialize round trip, as below:

```
var backToJSON = ListItems.Select(o => System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(o.Fields.AdditionalData));
var stronglyTypedItems = backToJSON.Select(jsonO => System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataItem>(jsonO));
```

***Is there a way to do this, either with smarter OData or something in Graph API I haven't seen, without taking what used to be JSON and sending it back through JSON Serializers twice?***

More details below:
Sample output JSON from Graph Explorer, where `value` contains an array of :

```
"value" : [ 
    { "id": "1001, 
      "fields": { 
        "Column" : "true", 
        "Column2" : "value2", 
        "Column3" : "65" 
      } 
    }, 
    { "id": "1002, 
      "fields": { 
  <and so forth until the array terminates>
  ]
}
```

Corresponding C# Class (literally built using "Paste JSON as class"):

```
Public class DataItem {
  public bool Column {get; set;}
  public string Column2 {get; set;}
  public int Column3 {get; set;}
}
```

The "Helper" classes in the C# Graph API deliver *mostly* transformed into the array of fields I actually need:

```
        private static GraphServiceClient graphClient;

        public static IListItemsCollectionRequest LicenseExpirationsList => graphClient
            .Sites["<guid>"]
            .Lists["<nameOfList>"].Items
            .Request()
            .Header("Accept", "application/json;odata.metadata=none")
            .Select("fields,id")
            .Expand("fields");

            var ListItems = (await GraphHelper.LicenseExpirationsList.GetAsync()).CurrentPage;


// JSON round tripping through JSONSerializer to get the strong type...
// But why? ListItems.Fields.AdditionalData is a Dictionary of JSON elements in the first place!

            var backToJSON = ListItems.Select(o => System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(o.Fields.AdditionalData));
            var stronglyTypedItems = backToJSON.Select(jsonO => System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataItem>(jsonO));
 

            return stronglyTypedItems;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could [customize the client's JSON serialization](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v4.md) to return a derived type of default `FieldValueSet`.

First, define your own extended `FieldValueSet`:

```
public class FieldValueSetWithDataItem : FieldValueSet
{
    public bool Column { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public int Column3 { get; set; }
}
```

Second, [implement your own JSON converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#support-polymorphic-deserialization):

```
class CustomFieldValueSetJsonConverter : JsonConverter<FieldValueSet>
{
    private static readonly JsonEncodedText ODataTypeProperty 
        = JsonEncodedText.Encode("@odata.type");
    private static readonly JsonEncodedText IdProperty 
        = JsonEncodedText.Encode("id");
    private static readonly JsonEncodedText ColumnProperty 
        = JsonEncodedText.Encode("Column");
    private static readonly JsonEncodedText Column2Property 
        = JsonEncodedText.Encode("Column2");
    private static readonly JsonEncodedText Column3Property
        = JsonEncodedText.Encode("Column3");

    public override FieldValueSet Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var result = new FieldValueSetWithDataItem();
        using var doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
        var root = doc.RootElement;

        foreach (var element in root.EnumerateObject())
        {
            if (element.NameEquals(ODataTypeProperty.EncodedUtf8Bytes))
            {
                result.ODataType = element.Value.GetString();
            }
            else if (element.NameEquals(IdProperty.EncodedUtf8Bytes))
            {
                result.Id = element.Value.GetString();
            }
            else if (element.NameEquals(ColumnProperty.EncodedUtf8Bytes))
            {
                result.Column = element.Value.GetBoolean();
            }
            else if (element.NameEquals(Column2Property.EncodedUtf8Bytes))
            {
                result.Column2 = element.Value.GetString();
            }
            else if (element.NameEquals(Column3Property.EncodedUtf8Bytes))
            {
                result.Column3 = element.Value.GetInt32();
            }
            else
            {
                // Capture unknown property in AdditionalData
                if (result.AdditionalData is null)
                {
                    result.AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                }
                result.AdditionalData.Add(element.Name, element.Value.Clone());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        FieldValueSet value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // To support roundtrip serialization:
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WriteString(ODataTypeProperty, value.ODataType);
        writer.WriteString(IdProperty, value.Id);

        if (value is FieldValueSetWithDataItem dataItem)
        {
            writer.WriteBoolean(ColumnProperty, dataItem.Column);
            writer.WriteString(Column2Property, dataItem.Column2);
            writer.WriteNumber(Column3Property, dataItem.Column3);
        }

        if (value.AdditionalData is not null)
        {
            foreach (var kvp in value.AdditionalData)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(kvp.Key);
                ((JsonElement)kvp.Value).WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }
        
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Last, use the JSON converter when making your request:

```
// Use custom JSON converter when deserializing response
var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
serializerOptions.Converters.Add(new CustomFieldValueSetJsonConverter());

var responseSerializer = new Serializer(serializerOptions);
var responseHandler = new ResponseHandler(responseSerializer);

var request = (ListItemsCollectionRequest)client.Sites[""].Lists[""].Items.Request();

var listItems = await request
    .WithResponseHandler(responseHandler)
    .GetAsync();
```

To access your column values:

```
var col3 = ((FieldValueSetWithDataItem)listItem.Fields).Column3;
```

Comment: Seems like that somewhat exposes what happens more or less automatically in the round trip I already have? `ListItems.Select(o => Serialize(o.Fields.AdditionalData)).Select(jsonO => Deserialize<DataItem>(jsonO));` I also wonder if there's a way to get Graph API to dispense with the layered metadata and return just the fields in a JSON array.

Comment: If you have roundtrip, instead of adding an extra field to the additional properties, you can create a derived type of FieldSetValue with extra properties, or have the converter to collect the deserialized objects in a list.

Comment: I must be not understanding what it means to "have roundtrip". roundtrip from what through what back to what? Please unpack that?

Comment: When I said "round trip", I meant you want to deserialize the fields into an object, that later will be serialized and sent to MS Graph. The way the JSON converter works changes the default serialization because it adds a `DataItem` property that is not originally there. In this case, when serializing the object back, you will need to remove the property and put the 3 column properties back.

Comment: The column values are returned as properties on [`FieldValueSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fieldvalueset?view=graph-rest-1.0) type. The `AdditionalData` is a JSON serialization trick that captures all additional properties that are unknown to static typed `FieldValueSet`. Since those properties are known to you, so it makes sense you create a derived class from `FieldValueSet` and use a custom JSON converter to create instances, see my updated answer.

Comment: No... I don't want to contain a custom class in the Graph response I'd like to learn if Graph can be directed to return `{ "fields" : [  {DataItemJsonText}, {DataItemJsonText}, {DataItemJsonText} ] }` instead of `{ "value" : [ { "id" : "1", "fields" : {DataItemJsonText} }, { "id" : "1", "fields" : {DataItemJsonText} }, (etc) ] }`, because C# and System.Text.Json have enormous abilities to transform JSON properly Or, if what it does return can be processed without the round-trip through Linq/Serialize. Largely, this is because the useful data in any SharePoint list is always in `AdditionalData`

Comment: Short answer is no, you can't return an array as the value for `fields`. MS Graph docs clearly state that the columns are captured in an object of type FieldValueSet, so it has to be an object in C#. The AdditionalData is used to capture custom properties. The way I showed you is how you could use Text.Json to customize JSON serialization. If you need an array, you either save an array of values (not JSON elements) in AdditionalData and use `AdditionalData.Values`, or could define a custom type to inherit from both `FieldValueSet` and `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Seems like I could inherit `FieldValueSet` and then define an `IDataItem` implementation exposing the properties I want instead of `DataItem`... which would avoid the extra roundtrip, maintain a FieldValueSet for PATCH updates...  and also make something a DI architecture would tolerate... Thank you, @weichch, I think you made me a better programmer today.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [HttpProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.httpprovider?view=graph-core-dotnet) of the GraphServiceClient helpful in this scenario:

```
        var listItemsCollectionRequest = graphServiceClient
         .Sites["<guid>"]
         .Lists["<nameOfList>"]
         .Items
         .Request()
         .Header("Accept", "application/json;odata.metadata=none")
         .Select("fields,id")
         .Expand("fields");

        using (var requestMessage = listItemsCollectionRequest.GetHttpRequestMessage())
        {
            using var responseMessage = await graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(requestMessage);

            //deserialize the response body into DataItem
        }
```

By using the HttpProvider you can directly work with the response from the Graph API and deserialize the response body into your custom class.